# how to fix reverse for logout not found in django python

Tags: django, python-3.x

i m customizing my admin page but getting this error Reverse for 'logout' not found. 'logout' is not a valid view function or pattern name

i have created admin directory creted the urls added base site and login templates. also created a view for logout in common directory

class LogoutView(RedirectView):

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    auth_logout(self.request)
    return super(LogoutView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))

rlpatterns = [
path('admin/', include(('jat_admin.urls', 'jat_admin'), namespace="admin")),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('common/', include(('common.urls', 'common'), namespace="common")),
path("login/", views.LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
path("logout/", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
path('social-auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace="social")),
path("", views.HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
```

Comment: Where is the code that is calling a reverse on "logout". Can you include that please?

Comment: your details are not enough. where the error occurs? which line? post that line. did your app has a name? I mean __*app_name*__. posting more of error can help.

Comment: this one?class LogoutView(RedirectView):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        auth_logout(self.request)
        return super(LogoutView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))

Comment: @LostGost C:\Users\Abdul Monim\jat\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 622

Comment: @AbdulMonim your error is for logout but the part you send is used login reverse.where is the error? and in urls.py you have app_name ?

Comment: @LostGost where i have to define logout reverse.? yes i have app name in urls.py

Comment: @AbdulMonim where you get this error: 'Reverse for 'logout' not found. 'logout' is not a valid view function or pattern name ' ? when you try to access it in browser or when you user reverse() func?

Comment: when i open my admin page in browser i.e 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Comment: Please edit your original question with all the details needed and first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: yes.edit your question. post all of the error log and where error happens(based on error). and add your full code of urls.py file